# How can I deploy a Windows Phone App on devices which I do not own?

Tags: cordova, deployment, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have to develop a Cordova Application which should also be available for Windows Phones.

What I want to do:

- Send "other People" a Artifact which they can install via SD Card / Download
- Release and update the application not via the Windows Store (Download/SD Card)

I'm used to that from Android Development (send apk, profit..) and at the moment I can't see any convenient way to accomplish this.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 3):

[Generate a promotional code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185377.aspx) for your beta testers.

Older store apps had a "beta" setting.  Using a promotional code is the new way, and offers improved experience.

Another method is to hide the app in the store, and only let people with a direct link download it. You set this via [distribution and visibilty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt148548.aspx#dist_vis).

Comment: I think the OP asked about a method bypassing the store: *'Release and update the application not via the Windows Store '*.

Comment: @Romasz, correct. Since the OP mentioned being used to android, it was unclear whether they knew of options for releasing to store other than only being released for all to view/download. Without knowing who "other people" are, even Michal Kozaks' answer could prove beyond their skill/comfort level, however, that is a good answer if they are technical.

Comment: If its possible to list the app in the Windows Store as "private" it should be fine. I'll take a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If "other people" download Windows Software Development Kit they can use Windows Phone Application Deployment software. They just download your package and install it using this. But they have to unlock their phones so it can be tricky. But as I can read here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx

everyone can unlock one phone without having developer account (just need to have an account). But it's written for WP8 but so I'm not certain if it might work.
Updating an app is done using the console

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632395.aspx